# Firebase / iOS updating data

Tags: objective-c, firebase

How do I update a generated child record inside of Firebase? I'm getting the error below about special characters, is there a way to generate the child auto IDs without special characters?

This is what the child auto id looks like: `-JmJFEe-Kq4BLLNfR0Ta`

My code:

```
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"refString"];
    A0SimpleKeychain *keychain = [[Application sharedInstance] store];
    A0UserProfile *profile = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[keychain dataForKey:@"profile"]];
    // Create a reference to a Firebase location
    NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://firebaseUrlGoesHere/%@",profile.nickname];
    // Create a reference to a Firebase location
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:theUrl];
    // Write data to Firebase

    NSDictionary *feedItems = @{
                                @"description" : description.text,
                                @"url": url.text,
                                @"category" : category.text
                                };
    //Firebase unique child I'm trying to update
    Firebase *post1Ref = [ref childByAppendingPath:myString];
    [post1Ref setValue: feedItems];
```

This is the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(childByAppendingPath:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

I've tried also using updateChildValues, this returns the same error.

```html
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString
    NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"refString"];
    A0SimpleKeychain *keychain = [[Application sharedInstance] store];
    A0UserProfile *profile = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[keychain dataForKey:@"profile"]];
    // Create a reference to a Firebase location
    NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://firebaseurlgoeshere/%@",profile.nickname];
    // Create a reference to a Firebase location
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:theUrl];
    Firebase *ref2 = [ref childByAppendingPath: myString];
    // Write data to Firebase

    NSDictionary *feedItems = @{
                                @"description" : description.text,
                                @"url": url.text,
                                @"category" : category.text
                                };
    
   [ref2 updateChildValues:feedItems];
```

Comment: So, what happens if, just as a test, you hard coded the child ID like: `Firebase *post1Ref = [ref childByAppendingPath @"-JmJFEe-Kq4BLLNfR0Ta"];` Does this still produce the error?

Comment: So hard coding in the id seems to work, it's not crashing

Comment: My instinct would be to check the value of `myString`, but I'm sure you have already checked that a billion times.

Comment: ugh the tunnel vision is real. I had it stuck in my head that mystring was just bringing in the id value, so I concatenating it on the end of the data path. The string actually was carrying the entire path along with the id value. Thanks for the help, I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one for helping me through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [childByAutoId](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/childByAutoId) is what you are looking for.

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *feedItems = @{
                            @"description" : description.text,
                            @"url": url.text,
                            @"category" : category.text
                            };

Firebase *post1Ref = [ref childByAutoId];
[post1Ref setValue: feedItems];
```

More from Firebase here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-lists

Comment: By using childByAutoId, it's creating a new record, I just want to update the existing record. I guess I could delete the existing and create a new one. That seems really inefficent.

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood you then. You definitely shouldn't have to delete, and then re-add.